# SQL Serverの照合順序のBIN2とCS_AS_KS_WSの違いについて

Tags: sql-server

SQL Serverは2017で、照合順序を何にすればよいか検討しております。
Japanese_XJIS_140_BIN2
Japanese_XJIS_140_CS_AS_KS_WS

上記の2種類のどちらにするかを検討中ですが、
BIN2のほうにした場合、以下は区別されると考えてよろしでしょうか？
CS:大文字と小文字を区別する。
AS:アクセントを区別する。
KS:カナ/かなを区別する。
WS:半角/全角を区別する。

区別されるのであれば、Japanese_XJIS_140_BIN2を採用したいと考えております。

よろしくお願い致します。